# how to use boost::asio::defer() in composing function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

On Boost 1.66, Asio have [deprecated](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html) the `asio_handler_is_continuation` hook function, promoting usage of `defer` function. [It seems that](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Asio-defer-dispatch-and-post-differences-td4700883.html) `defer` function is behaving exactly the same as `post` when asio_handler_is_continuation==true. However, the way of using `defer` is different from the way of using `asio_handler_is_continuation`, and I am not sure how to properly use `defer`.

**EDIT**: I think the sample below is too verbose to clearly express what i mean. Here's shorter example:

```
async_read_until(stream, read_buffer, "\r\n", 
    [](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if(!ec)
            async_write(stream, write_buffer, some_handler);
    })
```

Now when `async_read_until` is completed, the lambda handler passed will be invoked using some means equivalent to `boost::asio::post`. But `async_write` inside the lambda handler is continuation from last async task, So I want to invoke the lambda handler using `defer` to take adventage of optimization.

Is there any way to use `defer` (instead of `post`) to invoke the lambda handler in above example?

**ORIGINAL POST**: I am trying to write a simple initating function `async_echo` similar to the one in [beast document](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html), except that the part that calls `boost::asio::async_write` will be called as a continuation. To achieve this, prior intermediate operation `boost::asio::async_read_until` must call the handler `*this` as a continuation.

This is the part that I am referring in the async_echo example of the beast document:

```
template<class AsyncStream, class Handler>
void echo_op<AsyncStream, Handler>::
operator()(boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    // Store a reference to our state. The address of the state won't
    // change, and this solves the problem where dereferencing the
    // data member is undefined after a move.
    auto& p = *p_;

    // Now perform the next step in the state machine
    switch(ec ? 2 : p.step)
    {
        // initial entry
        case 0:
            // read up to the first newline
            p.step = 1;
            return boost::asio::async_read_until(p.stream, p.buffer, "\r", std::move(*this));

        case 1:
            // write everything back
            p.step = 2;
            // async_read_until could have read past the newline,
            // use buffers_prefix to make sure we only send one line
            return boost::asio::async_write(p.stream,
                boost::beast::buffers_prefix(bytes_transferred, p.buffer.data()), std::move(*this));

        case 2:
            p.buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
            break;
    }

    // Invoke the final handler. The implementation of `handler_ptr`
    // will deallocate the storage for the state before the handler
    // is invoked. This is necessary to provide the
    // destroy-before-invocation guarantee on handler memory
    // customizations.
    //
    // If we wanted to pass any arguments to the handler which come
    // from the `state`, they would have to be moved to the stack
    // first or else undefined behavior results.
    //
    p_.invoke(ec);
    return;
}
```

On pre-1.66 days, I could simply hook the function as follows:

```
template <Function, Handler>
friend bool asio_handler_is_continuation(echo_op<Function, Handler>* handler)
{
    using boost::asio::asio_handler_is_continuation;
    return handler.p_->step == 1 || 
        asio_handler_is_continuation(std::addressof(handler.p_->handler()));
}
```

inside the declaration of `echo_op`.

Starting from Boost 1.66, the code above is not likely to have any effect (without `BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATION` macro). So I should be using `defer`.

But since `boost::asio::async_read_until` has [a guarantee](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html) that "Invocation of the handler will be performed in a manner equivalent to using boost::asio::io_context::post().", `*this` will not be invoked using `defer`, that is, as a continuation.

Is there any workaround that makes `boost::asio::async_read_until` invoke the handler using `defer`? And is there any good examples that utilize `defer` function?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this as well. And your question exactly reflects my thoughts on the matter. The semantics of `asio_handler_is_continuation` are different from the use of `post` versus `defer`.

Comment: @VinnieFalco We have to use `asio_handler_is_continuation` in this case. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around a bit, it turns out that `asio_handler_is_continuation` is not deprecated; and there is no way to replace it with `defer` currently.

To redirect any `post` calls to `defer`, I provided following custom executor:

```
template<typename UnderlyingExecutor, typename std::enable_if<boost::asio::is_executor<UnderlyingExecutor>::value, int>::type = 0>
class continuation_executor
{
    private:
        UnderlyingExecutor _ex;

    public:

        continuation_executor(UnderlyingExecutor ex)
            :_ex(ex){}

        template<class Function, class Allocator>
        void post(Function f, Allocator a)
        {
            std::cout<<"Redirected to defer()"<<std::endl;
            _ex.defer(BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(Function)(f),a);
        }

        template<class Function, class Allocator>
        void defer(Function f, Allocator a)
        {
            std::cout<<"defer() called"<<std::endl;
            _ex.defer(BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(Function)(f),a);
        }

        template<class Function, class Allocator>
        void dispatch(Function f, Allocator a)
        {
            std::cout<<"dispatch() called"<<std::endl;
            _ex.dispatch(BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(Function)(f),a);
        }

        auto context() -> decltype(_ex.context())
        {
            return _ex.context(); 
        }

        void on_work_started()
        {
            _ex.on_work_started();
        }
        void on_work_finished()
        {
            _ex.on_work_finished();
        }
};
```

It is really a trivial executor, relying entirely to the underlying executor, with `continuation_executor::post` that redirects into underlying executor's `defer`.

But when I pass a handler to `async_read_some` with something like `bind_executor(conti_exec, handler)`, I get following output:

```
dispatch() called
```

So the passed handler does not get scheduled via `post()`; it is scheduled by some other means. Concretely, built-in async function like `asio::async_read_some` schedule the internal operation object via `scheduler::post_immediate_completion`, then `io_context::run` executes the operation.

Upon completion of the async operation, `complete` method of the operation object is called to execute the user-provided handler. That `complete` method, at least on current implementation, uses associated executor's `dispatch` method to run the handler. There is no place for above hook. So it is completely obsolate; attempt to use `defer` instead of `asio_handler_is_continuation` is out of luck.

What I stated on my question, "Starting from Boost 1.66, the code above is not likely to have any effect (without BOOST_ASIO_NO_DEPRECATION macro).", is plain wrong. `asio_handler_is_continuation` is still in effect, and it is [not deprecated as of 1.67](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_is_continuation.html).

This is the evidence that `asio_handler_is_continuation` is still in effect:

```
  // Start an asynchronous send. The data being sent must be valid for the
  // lifetime of the asynchronous operation.
  template <typename ConstBufferSequence, typename Handler>
  void async_send(base_implementation_type& impl,
      const ConstBufferSequence& buffers,
      socket_base::message_flags flags, Handler& handler)
  {
    bool is_continuation =
      boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers::is_continuation(handler);

    // Allocate and construct an operation to wrap the handler.
    typedef reactive_socket_send_op<ConstBufferSequence, Handler> op;
    typename op::ptr p = { boost::asio::detail::addressof(handler),
      op::ptr::allocate(handler), 0 };
    p.p = new (p.v) op(impl.socket_, impl.state_, buffers, flags, handler);

    BOOST_ASIO_HANDLER_CREATION((reactor_.context(), *p.p, "socket",
          &impl, impl.socket_, "async_send"));

    start_op(impl, reactor::write_op, p.p, is_continuation, true,
        ((impl.state_ & socket_ops::stream_oriented)
          && buffer_sequence_adapter<boost::asio::const_buffer,
            ConstBufferSequence>::all_empty(buffers)));
    p.v = p.p = 0;
  }
```

Note that it uses `boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers` to find out if the handler is continuation. `boost_asio_handler_cont_helpers` internally invokes `asio_handler_is_continuation`.

`async_send` is used by `async_write_some` internally. I did not check every built-in async tasks that asio library provides, But I am pretty sure that other async tasks executes it's handler the same way.

So, if you want built-in async tasks to execute your handler as continuation, you will have to rely on `asio_handler_is_continuation`. `defer` is not going to *entirely* replace it! `defer` can only be used when you schedule your handler directly from your code.

Comment: This sounds good in theory, but Networking.TS has no equivalent to `asio_handler_is_continuation`. Is that functionality going away?

Comment: @VinnieFalco I think so. Without controlling the way how internal operation is submitted to `io_context`, The effect we want from `asio_handler_is_continuation` is impossible. And upon a quick looking, Networking.TS does not provide a concrete restriction on how work is submitted to `io_context`. So, unless they provide an indicator like `net_handler_is_continuation`, that functionality is certainly going away :/

Answer (score 5):

This has puzzled me in the past also.

`Executor::defer` and `Executor::post` both perform the same operation, except for this note:

> Note: Although the requirements placed on defer are identical to post, the use of post conveys a preference that the caller does not block the first step of f1's progress, whereas defer conveys a preference that the caller does block the first step of f1. One use of defer is to convey the intention of the caller that f1 is a continuation of the current call context. The executor may use this information to optimize or otherwise adjust the way in which f1 is invoked. —end note

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html

So it seems that responsibility to chaining continuations has been made an implementation detail of the `Executor` model.

Which as far as I can tell, means that all you need to do is call the free function `defer(executor, handler)` and the executor will 'do the right thing'

### update:

Found some documentation which shows how to chain handlers through the final executor:

source of documentation: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio-tr2/blob/master/doc/executors.qbk

example: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/executors/blob/v0.2-branch/src/examples/executor/async_op_2.cpp

see lines 38+ in async_op_2.cpp

Comment: But I cant call `defer(executor, handler)` because `async_read_until` is responsible to call the handler. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @herambled I can't. There's doesn't seem to be enough information in the asio docs.

Comment: That minimalistic documentation... Anyway, thank you for the effort to write an answer. I think I found a *kind of* workaround.

Comment: @herambled In the past I have emailed Christopher Kohlhoff for help. He has graciously responded twice without mentioning money. He might be happy to explain it - particularly if you offer to update the documentation for him ;)

Comment: @herambled see update. You manually extract the handler's function and pass it into your own handler.

Comment: This is my goto de-facto documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_io/writing_composed_operations.html.

Comment: PS I think it's a bit hostile to _downvote_ an excellent answer from someone with heaps of real life Asio expertise. If it's not helpful/doesn't solve your problem, don't upvote, and discuss. We're all here sharing.

Comment: I see I could use the technique in your update for my 'workaround'. My workaround is to provide a custom executor that have `post` function that conditionaly redirects to `defer`. I'll post my workaround after testing it.

Comment: @herambled That is the approach described here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4242.html#executors.on_the_need_for_dispatch__post_and_defer

Comment: @VinnieFalco Oh, it's from author of Boost.asio. I actually like that idea, it is more intuitive way. It's pity that current version of `async_read` does not use `_ex.post` to schedule the handler. Well, they only added `defer` at Boost 1.66, which is fairly recent version, and in the future more modern features will be introduced. So the behavior described in the paper might get into the Boost.asio and, hopefully Networking.TS!

Comment: First of all, there's no "they" there's just "him" (lol). This is what he had to say: "N.B: Most async operations implementations within asio never "complete immediately" according to the networking TS definition, meaning they always use ex.dispatch() and never ex.post(). This is a todo item." I guess that agrees with your observation.

Comment: @VinnieFalco Great! I eager to see "him" implements that :). And I hope Networking.TS explicitly mention about it, instead of leaving it to the complier makers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that the comments in the code found on https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio-tr2/blob/master/doc/executors.qbk actually contain the most detailed description about `dispatch()`, `post()` and `defer()`.

`defer()` postpones the processing of the newly created job to after the current job has finished. It does *not* postpone it past other queued jobs. postponing to after the completion of the current job has the big advantage, that the new job can then run in the same thread as the current job. The default executor will try to do so. And as the new job will most likely use some or more data from the current job, staying in the same thread and thus the same CPU core greatly improves cache locality and thus reduces total execution time and increases throughput.

In other words: In those of your completion handlers / tasks, that launch exactly one new completion handler / task, you almost always want to use `defer()` instead of `post()`. That's especially true, if the new task is launched towards the end of the current task.

However, those tasks, that launch more than one new task, should only submit the most related task (which will often be the last task) via `defer()`, and use `post()` for all the other ones.

Only for those tasks, that are really simple, think about submitting them via `dispatch()` instead of `post()` or `queue()`: If rules permit it (like the strand, that they are dispatched into, has currently an empty queue), then they will run directly, avoiding all the queuing and unqueuing latency.

Comment: Note that the text reflects the 2015 [P0113R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0113r0.html) which revises N4242.